# How I can controller the reach of WIFI antenna?

Tags: wireless-communication

I would like to know, which antenna 802.11 model, it your reach can be controlled.

In a some researches, I'm discovered a tool called "iwconfig", native on some Operation systems Unix Like. It is used by own OS to manager interfaces wireless.

Some options of tool:

```
interface essid {NNN|any|on|off}
interface mode {managed|ad-hoc|master|...}
interface freq N.NNN[k|M|G]
interface channel N
interface bit {N[k|M|G]|auto|fixed}
interface rate {N[k|M|G]|auto|fixed}
interface enc {NNNN-NNNN|off}
interface key {NNNN-NNNN|off}
interface power {period N|timeout N|saving N|off}
interface nickname NNN
interface nwid {NN|on|off}
interface ap {N|off|auto}
interface txpower {NmW|NdBm|off|auto}
interface sens N
interface retry {limit N|lifetime N}
interface rts {N|auto|fixed|off}
interface frag {N|auto|fixed|off}
interface modulation {11g|11a|CCK|OFDMg|...}
interface commit (Para salvar alterações)
```

I'm using an device USB TP-Link N TL-WN823N, 2.4 Ghz

But this devices is basic. I can only set some settings like, Mode of operation (ad hoc, monitor, manager), channel, essid...

I believe that I can control your reach, I should to manager the txpower or sensibility (sens). When I try to set it, the system returns that operation is not supported by device. Possibly is because this device is not dedicate to used like access point.

So, I would like to know if are some antenna 802.11 that the reach can be controlled by txpower, sensibility or something
physical to break the reach

Comment: I think you have asked on the wrong site. It is also not clear what exactly you are asking.